# Difference between internet path and AS path

Tags: bgp

As per my understanding, the Internet is the interconnection of ASes where BGP is a kind of "glue". BGP carries routing information from one AS to another. Also, the AS path is one of the several attributes of BGP. I also know that the BGP shown path(control path) and the actual path(data path) may be different. So, I wonder what may be the mistakes if using the Internet path and AS path synonymously? Please clarify it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the Internet is the interconnection of ASes where BGP is a kind of "glue".

I think it's important to understand that the concept of ASes only makes sense when talking about how BGP operates.  It doesn't make much sense in other contexts. So  I think your definition puts emphasis in the wrong place.

I'm unaware of any accepted definition of "Internet path."  I guess you're free to define it the way you want, but others may not understand what you mean.  One would have to see exactly how you use the term to determine what inaccuracies there may be.

Comment: Perhaps the OP means the difference between routes learned via BGP  and the route installed in the forwarding table. But I agree, as it is, the question is unclear.

Comment: Agreed, I've never heard the term 'internet path' specifically before. AS Path is a well accepted term meant to indicate the BGP learned path for any given network in the router's BGP route table as learned from BGP Peer(s). The AS Path for any given network may change with any given table update so it is not a static entity and may be very different for one network vs. another. Internet path might be intended to be synonomous but you might as well just use AS Path and be accurate. For anyone not familiar with BGP you could say 'route path' and might be understood well enough.